# Run an exe every 5 minutes with powershell scheduledtask

Tags: powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a task to execute every 5 minutes using powershell. The code below works but terminates after some time. Any ideas what might be causing that? Is it the code or should i look elsewhere? Thanks, Alex

```
$Ale = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "C:\Users\User\revie\rev.exe"
$Tle = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Once -At (Get-Date) -RepetitionInterval (New-TimeSpan -Minutes 10)
$Ple = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal "domain\User"
$Sle = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet
$Dle = New-ScheduledTask -Action $Ale -Trigger $Tle -Principal $Ple -Settings $Sle
Register-ScheduledTask meterp1 -InputObject $Dle
```

Comment: Maybe `-Once` and `-RepetitionInterval` don't work nicely with each other?

Comment: basicly it does what you can do with the task scheduler, if you cant use once and repetitions at the same time there, you wont be able to in powershell either

Comment: things look good to me, maybe `meterp1` should be in quotes, which error are you getting? from docs it looks like you can use `-Once` and `-RepetitionInterval` just fine. `Get-Help New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`

Comment: There is no error ,, it works fine and then after some time it stops,, (btw it is on a remote machine with no access to the gui)

Comment: How long does it take before it stops working?

Answer (score -1):

Use SchTasks.exe for this task:

```
schtasks.exe /create /tn "MyTask" /tr "C:\Users\User\revie\rev.exe"" /sc minute /mo 5
```

SchTasks Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks

- /create specifies that a task will be created.
- /tn is the task name.
- /tr is the exe file path.
- /sc is the time format.

Comment: A solution :), but not really a powershell solution which the title specifies.

Comment: @JimWolff I shared a clean solution without any problem :)